# fade out container, change content, fade in container

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade out a container div, then replace another div inside it, then after all content is loaded, fade in the container div again. My code fades out and loads the content but opacity stays at 0. Can someone point me how to make this work? Why does the opacity stay at 0?

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $('#content').fadeOut(600, function(){
            $("#container").css("opacity", "0");
            $.get("frontpage.html", function(data) {
                $("#content").replaceWith(data), function(){
                    $("#container").css("opacity", "1");
                };
            });
        });
    });
```

and html is simply:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: try to use `.done()`  `$.get(Replace_Part_Here).done(return_opacity)` and keep eyes on console for errors this `.replaceWith(data), function(){` should gives you an error

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's picking up that last call to `function()`.  Try running your code in the same callback.

```
      $.get("frontpage.html", function(data) {
            $("#content").replaceWith(data);
            $("#container").css("opacity", "1");
        });
```